# Magento 1 stop backup process

Tags: magento-1.9

I started a backup from the back-end, and my website switch to maintenance mode.But it is taking very long time to backup, is it possible to stop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

ps -aux | grep 'php bin/magento'

use second column number or [PID] into this command kill -9 [PID]

Tell me if its works or not

Comment: That would be a solution for magento 2 - but OP is asking for a solution on magento 1

Answer (score 0):

Please remove maintenance.flag file from var directory. your site will back